# Solid summary of what encryption remains strong after recent events

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, nsa

Following the recent government hacking (and subsequent news and fallout), I'm wondering what crypto-systems remain strong (and why) and what crypto-systems were exploited too heavily to be reliable. I'm wondering what will remain strong for the foreseeable future and why these systems were not affected (while the others presumably were).

I tried to find the information on the following and many other pages, but they were not very helpful in this case…

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_encryption_systems
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_cryptography

Perhaps someone can help me understand this.

Comment: Nothing has changed, really. You shouldn't use Dual_EC_DRBG, but then again, we've known you shouldn't use it since 2007. We know that certificate authorities are a weak link in the chain, but we've always known that. Snowden et al have said that one of the few defenses remaining is strong cryptography.

Comment: @Reid I read something about SSL being exploited by them is that totally not accurate?  Also, I read that elliptic curve and matrix-based crypto were considered very secure, and RSA and most of the other schemes remained.  Was most of their hacking like at the application-level (like backdoors) or were they actually able to attack some of the cryptosystems?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NSA's own nuclear, military, navy, airforce and classified government networks are probably some of the most secure systems on the planet. They need to be extremely strong to protect the armed forces, government and populace. However the same cannot be said for their publicly recommended encryption systems because recent leaks have shown their intention is to backdoor/weaken those systems/standards that are in commercial/public use so they can use their surveillance network to monitor what everyone is doing. Their aim is totalitarian control and subversion of democracy.

They have not just been weakening one standard (Dual EC DBRG), they have been weakening a lot of them. You would be ill advised to continue using them. As of 2013-10-15 The Wikipedia link you gave [provides a good list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA_encryption_systems#Public_systems) of those likely compromised systems to avoid. Until we know the full extent of the damage to cryptography in general it is better to lean on the side of caution. For starters that means avoiding any standard to do with NSA/NIST.

**Standards with NSA involvement to avoid:**

> **Suite B** - set of cryptographic algorithms promulgated by the NSA as part of its Cryptographic Modernization Program
>
> **Advanced Encryption Standard (AES)** - an encryption
>   algorithm, selected by NIST after a public competition. In 2003, NSA
>   certified AES for Type 1 use in *some* NSA-approved systems.
>
> **Secure Hash Algorithm** - a widely used family of hash algorithms developed by NSA
>   based on earlier designs by Ron Rivest.
>
> **Digital Signature Algorithm**
>
> **Data Encryption Standard (DES)**
>
> **Skipjack** - the cipher developed for Clipper and finally published in 1998.
>
> **Clipper chip** - a controversial failure that convinced NSA that it was advisable to stay out of the public arena.
>
> **Security-Enhanced Linux** - not strictly an encryption system, but a recognition that in the 21st century, operating system improvements are vital to information security as well.

**So what is left that is still good to use?**

- At the perfect security end you have got one-time pads and other
  cryptosystems that are information-theoretically secure. These are
  still in use by governments today. They transfer the one-time pads
  between embassies with diplomatic bags etc which are protected under
  the Vienna Convention.
- After that you've got stream ciphers which attempt to mimic the
  one-time pad. These are likely still secure assuming you have a very
  long, quality random seed to begin with, an unbroken implementation
  and well designed CSPRNG. They do not offer perfect security however
  but would probably still frustrate the NSA.
- After that there is independently designed block ciphers that should
  be ok to use for less important things e.g. hard disk encryption. For
  example, Serpent, Twofish, Threefish etc. Remember you want 256 bits
  or greater to take into effect recent developments in quantum
  computing and cryptanalytic breakthroughs.
- Newer hashing algorithms not designed by NSA should be fine to use.
  Recent examples might be finalists in the recent NIST hash
  competition. Obviously steer clear of the finalised SHA-3 standard by
  NIST and use the original Keccak algorithm which has already been
  vetted by various cryptographers. You do not need NIST's "tweaks"
  that are being made to suit their purposes, not yours.
- Elliptic curve cryptography is not my area of expertise.
  However if you are going that route avoid the NIST recommended curves
  and use some independently vetted ones.
- Public key cryptography is fundamentally broken, especially with
  Certificate Authorities for authentication. The NSA only needs to
  compromise just one CA which is already trusted in your browser. Then
  they can silently MITM your connection and send you a false
  certificate signed by the same authority. Your browser will
  automatically accept it. Also because your web browser trusts over
  500 different certificate authorities they can actually just send you
  a certificate signed by one of the compromised authorities and your
  browser will silently accept it and show a green padlock. Most users
  will not notice this. This is regardless of whether the real
  certificate was signed by that authority in the first place. Remember
  the certificates in your browser is like a keychain of all the people
  you trust. If there is just one bad apple then the whole trust system
  breaks down.

  Public key cryptography is a nice idea in theory, but it breaks down in the real world. In today's
  world with all the internet backbones tapped by "Five Eyes" countries
  and numerous untrusted router hops along the way, you do not actually
  have an authentic channel to transfer the public key to someone in
  the first place. In other words you have no idea if the public key
  you are receiving is actually the one you want to receive and not an
  attacker's. There is no provable authenticity. If you really wanted to
  use public key cryptography you would transfer the public key to them
  in person and load it into your keychain as trusted. That lets you know for sure that this is the real key and not an attacker's key. Potentially you could at least verify a
  checksum/hash of the key over another channel e.g. telephone. It is
  probably harder for an attacker to synthesize someone's voice in
  real-time. The CIA or MI6 could probably pull it off though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65483/discussion-on-answer-by-nomoni-solid-summary-of-what-encryption-remains-strong-a).

Answer (score 2):

We don't know what NSA (or any other spy agency--the US isn't the only country with code breakers) has broken.  Other than Dual EC DRBG, we are left with everyone making their best guess, just like before.  The NIST elliptic curves and the SHA2 hashes and DSA all came from NSA, but that seems to be the only real reason to suspect anything bad about them.  Neither AES nor SHA3/Keccak have anything at all to do with NSA.

Comment: [NIST is required by law to consult with the NSA on new encryption standards](http://fcw.com/articles/2013/09/10/nist-nsa-response.aspx). And often these standards get unexplained alterations before they are finalized. Of course that doesn't indicate how much actual influence the NSA have on the process. It could just be a basic consultation, or they could manipulate the outcome (claiming there is a weakness in one of the standard they actually have difficulty with in order to push the decision to one they have an attack on), or they could be more active in manipulating the outcome.

Comment: Another example would be the [IPSec standard](http://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg12325.html).